# jsp oracle with javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

The problem is Code is working when rs.getString
(1) is integer number, but in my case it's a varchar primary key , how to fix this.

```
function getId(id){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="post";
    f.action='SelectBank1.jsp?id='+id;
    f.submit();
}

<%
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select IdwhichIsVarchar, description from  SomeDataBase where IS_VISIBLE = 1 order by description  ");
%>

<%
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr><td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>

<td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:green;font-weight:bold;color:white;" onclick="getId(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the value with quotes:

```
onclick="getId('<%=rs.getString(1)%>')"
```

Otherwise you will get such output for example:

```
onclick="getId(foo)"
```

And JavaScript will try to parse "foo" as variable thus fail. With the fix it will be:

```
onclick="getId('foo')"
```

And "foo" will be passed as a string to the function.

Comment: but when rs.getString(1) ... is 1 or 100, or whatever integer it's working , but when is abv_bg qwery or whatever varchar from db it's not working what quotes change

Comment: Numbers are passed as-is (as numeric value) thus don't need quotes around them. This is the same in most, if not all, programming languages pretty sure JSP is one of them as well.